# Why is it a "vexed question", rather than a "vexing question"?

Tags: participles

If I understand it correctly, a "vexed question" is bothering, annoying, and frustrating us; not being bothered, annoyed, and frustrated by us. As such, I'd expect the active (present, -ing) participle, not the passive (past, -ed).

Yet, [Google N-Gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vexing%20question%2Cvexed%20question&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows that the term "vexed question" is about 3 times as prevalent as the "vexing question", and decades ago it was 10 or 20 times as widespread.

I remain vexed by this [vexing issue](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vexing%20issue%2Cvexed%20issue&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvexing%20issue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvexed%20issue%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Appears to be mostly a Britishism.  Here in the US I'm only familiar with "vexing question".

Comment: Interesting! Indeed, the counter-intuitive imbalance is much stronger in [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vexed+question%2Cvexing+question&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) than [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vexed+question%2Cvexing+question&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3), although the "vexed question" is still ahead in the Google American English corpus.

Comment: Understand that Google Books "American English" is biased by British English, either by  books by British authors, or by American authors that adopt a British style.

Answer (score 1):

If you search ***vexed question*** in the available dictionaries, you will find that it is a British idiomatic expression which, according to [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vexed-question), means

> an issue that is much debated and discussed

If you look up ***vexing question***, however, it is interesting that Google still gives entries for ***vexed questions***, and only one or two instances of ***vexing*** treated on its own. For example, [MWebster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vexing) defines it as

> causing or likely to cause vexation : VEXATIOUS. Ex: *a vexing problem*

Therefore, I believe that ***a vexing question*** is simply a question that vexes or annoys, whereas ***a vexed question*** is rather a complicated  [problem](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/vexed-question-issue-problem-etc) that has caused a lot of discussion and argument and is difficult to solve.